# Create a string variable as-is containing mixed quotes

Tags: php, string

How can I take a string with lots of mixed double and single quotes:

```
curl -A 'Curl/2.5' -d '{"key":"$api_key","message":{"html":"<p><h1>Hello World</h1><\/p>"}'
```

and create a string variable such as:

```
$curl_command = "curl -A 'Curl/2.5' -d '{"key":"$api_key","message":{"html":"<p><h1>Hello World</h1><\/p>"}'"
```

Without returning "unexpected ' errors"? I want to avoid changing the original string.

Comment: I'd like to hardcode the string in my php file with working php $variables inside the json part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use heredoc syntax and escape all the quotes and double quotes easily.

Here is the syntax for it.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Take care not leave space before the heredoc identifier.

Comment: What's the difference between EOD and EOT?

Comment: @JMC see my answer and you will understand... there is no difference. it doesn't matter what you use. You can use `EOD`, `EOT`, `blahblah`, or even `someStringYouWillAlsoNeedToStop`

Comment: Thanks I get it now. They switch between EOD and EOT in the manual making it appear to have meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of **`HEREDOC`** Syntax.

```
<?php
$api_key='xx2233';
$content=<<<EOD
curl -A 'Curl/2.5' -d '{"key":"$api_key","message":{"html":"<p><h1>Hello World</h1><\/p>"}'
EOD;

echo $curlCommand=$content;
```

**OUTPUT :**

> curl -A 'Curl/2.5' -d '{"key":"xx2233","message":{"html":" Hello World
>
> </p>"}

Answer (score 1):

You can use Heredoc:

```
$string = <<<someStringYouWillAlsoNeedToStop
curl -A 'Curl/2.5' -d '{"key":"$api_key","message":{"html":"<p><h1>Hello World</h1><\/p>"}'
someStringYouWillAlsoNeedToStop; // this ends your string
```

Beware that heredoc DOES parse your $variables.
If you don't want that, you should use Nowdoc by using single quotes around the first someStringYouWillNeedToStop:

```
$string = <<<'someStringYouWillAlsoNeedToStop'
curl -A 'Curl/2.5' -d '{"key":"$api_key","message":{"html":"<p><h1>Hello World</h1><\/p>"}'
someStringYouWillAlsoNeedToStop; // this ends your string
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) function to guarantee it's fully escaped:

```
$arg = escapeshellarg('{"key":"$api_key","message":{"html":"<p><h1>Hello World</h1><\/p>"}');
$curl_command = "curl -A 'Curl/2.5' -d '.$arg;
```